# Setting tabular width

Tags: tables, multicol

I'm using a `tabular` within `multicols` and would like to make a table extend its second column right to the edge of the column within `multicols`, so the column is pushed over but the text is still left justified. The code I'm trying to use this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Notation}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
$Q_r$ & Heat energy rejected \\
$Q_s$ & Heat energy supplied \\
$R$ & Real gas constant for fluid \\
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lX}` from the `tabularx` package.

Comment: @egreg: `\linewidth` would also work.

Comment: @egreg How would I set that just so it worked with the second column?

Comment: @Andy I can't understand. Do you want that the tabular extends into the second column?

Comment: @egreg Sorry I meant so you could choose different widths for different columns, say for column one a width of 4cm and for column two a width of 8cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the first column 4cm wide, flush with the left margin, and the second column to take all the available space, flush with the right margin, then

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

in the preamble and

```
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{@{}p{4cm}X@{}}
$Q_r$ & Heat energy rejected \\
$Q_s$ & Heat energy supplied \\
$R$ & Real gas constant for fluid \\
\end{tabularx}
```

should do.

Note that `a4wide` is an obsolete package that shouldn't be used any more (see `texdoc l2tabuen`).